# Die probability question involving 8-sided die

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An 8-sided die is rolled 15 times. What is the probability that a 2 appears exactly 2 times, a 3 appears exactly 3 times, …, and a 5 appears exactly 5 times?

I tried doing it using binomial probability taking (1/6)^2*(5/6)^13 etc but this seems tedious.

Comment: Since the die is eight-sided, the probability that the die lands on a particular side is $1/8$ rather than $1/6$.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it like this. Each time you roll the dice 15 times you generate a sequence of 15 digits, e.g. (1,2,2,2,1,8,6,7,5,4,4,3,1,2,3). Since the die is fair, each of these outcomes are equally likely so we can just count how many of these outcomes have the desired number of 2's, 3's, etc.

There are $8^{15}$ possible rolls that could occur. There are ${15 \choose 2}$ ways to choose which positions the twos could occur in, ${13 \choose 3}$ ways to choose the positions the threes could occur in, …

In total this yields the probability:

$$\frac{{15 \choose 2}{13 \choose 3}{9 \choose 4}{5 \choose 5}}{8^{15}}$$

Comment: thanks! why does this work without needing to use 1/8 etc

Comment: This works because the die is fair, so each of the digits is equally likely. Thus, each sequence of 15 rolls, e.g. (1,2,2,2,1,8,6,7,5,4,4,3,1,2,3), is equally likely. You can try to think of it like this. The numerator counts how many possible sequences there are that have the desired property, and we simply multiply this by the probability of that specific sequence occurring, $1/8^{15}$. Since these events are disjoint, we can just add all the probabilities.